# Spark in docker, setting memory for driver /executor

Tags: docker, apache-spark

I am running spark-master and spark-worker in a separate docker.

I can see them running

> ✗ ps -ef | grep spark root      3477  3441  0  1월05 ?      00:04:17
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java -cp
>   /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip node-master --port 7077
>   --webui-port 10080

I'm not sure if my workers are using 1g or 8g, I do set memory options via SparkConf

```
 conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "8g")
 conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "8g")
```

I can see `8g` in the web ui

[image]

Am I really using 8g? Is there a way to change the `Xmm1g` part which are shown in the command line under ps?

** edit

I'm running standalone cluster (not yarn), and using pyspark, It's not possible to use spark-submit python files in standalone cluster mode

> Currently, the standalone mode does not support cluster mode for
>   Python applications.

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not set these options in the code, because depending on cluster manager those options might not have an effect.

You should set those in spark-submit command.

Please refer to [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties).

> Spark properties mainly can be divided into two kinds: one is related
>   to deploy, like “spark.driver.memory”, “spark.executor.instances”,
>   this kind of properties may not be affected when setting
>   programmatically through SparkConf in runtime, or the behavior is
>   depending on which cluster manager and deploy mode you choose, so it
>   would be suggested to set through configuration file or spark-submit
>   command line options; another is mainly related to Spark runtime
>   control, like “spark.task.maxFailures”, this kind of properties can be
>   set in either way.

**UPDATE**

From [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#launching-applications-with-spark-submit):

```
# Run a Python application on a Spark standalone cluster
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  examples/src/main/python/pi.py \
  1000
```

Comment: I'm running standalone cluster (not yarn), and using pyspark, It's not possible to use spark-submit python files in standalone cluster mode.

Comment: Well. i believe these facts you should then mention in the question also.

Comment: And yet I see example of starting python with spark submit in official documentation. Added it to my answer.

Comment: I think the example is for when you are not using cluster.